# Zabbix Discovery JSON Formatting

Tags: linux, zabbix, json

I trying to create a discovery rule to monitor a enterprise application, and my script return the follow JSON.

```
{
    "data": [{
            "{#NODENAME}": "node1",
            "{#NODEINTERFACE}": ["eth0", "eth1"]
        },
        {
            "{#NODENAME}": "node2",
            "{#NODEINTERFACE}": ["eth2", "eth3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

On Zabbix Interface i created the discovery with the follow parameters:

**Name:**: Discovery nodes and interfaces

**Type**: Zabbix agent

**Key** app.discovery

And in "Filters" TAB:

**Type of calculation**: And/Or

---

The expected behavior on Zabbix is to create the followings keys:

**Format of keys:**

```
app.getinfo["{#NODENAME}","{#NODEINTERFACE}]
```

That is, for **each NODENAME** create **N** keys, **one for each interface**

**Discovery keys:**

```
app.getInfo["node1","eth0"]
app.getInfo["node1","eth1"]

app.getInfo["node2","eth2"]
app.getInfo["node2","eth3"]
```

---

The behavior received its:

If **Type of calculation** is **And/Or**, Zabbix **not** create the items

And if **Type of calculation** is **Or**, Zabbix create **one** item for each NODENAME, and ignore/not recognize the NODEINTERFACE

---

My doubt is, How to create an discovery rule, For each NODENAME, create N items with the NODEINTERFACE information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the prototype key is likely wrong - quotes are not closed in `app.getinfo["{#NODENAME}","{#NODEINTERFACE}]`.

Second, your JSON should be like this:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "{#NODENAME}": "node1",
        "{#NODEINTERFACE}": "eth0"
    },
    {
        "{#NODENAME}": "node1",
        "{#NODEINTERFACE}": "eth1"
    },
    {
        "{#NODENAME}": "node2",
        "{#NODEINTERFACE}": "eth2"
    }
    {
        "{#NODENAME}": "node2",
        "{#NODEINTERFACE}": "eth3"
    }
]
}
```

Note how each entry must hold a single set of values you want to be represented in the created entities.